# How to make subsequent request to SAP Business One Service Layer from Django

Tags: django, sapb1

I want to use Django to make requests to SAP Business One Service Layer.  SAP B1 Service Layer requires initial login to establish a session.  I am able to authenticate and get a correct response with a returned session ID from the Service Layer.  There is a 30 minute timeout after successful login if there is no activity.  How can I save a session from another server (in this case the Service layer) to make additional requests?  Below is code of the initial SAP post request to the Login endpoint.

```
def AuthSAP(request):
     sap_url = "https://sap_url.com:50000/b1s/v2/Login"
    
     headers = {
        "authkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
        "Accept": "*/*",
        "Content-Type": "text/plain",
    }

    data = {
        "CompanyDB": "XXXXXXXX",
        "UserName": "XXXXXXXX",
        "Password": "XXXXXXX"
    }

    response = requests.post(sap_url, headers=headers, json=data)

    print("JSON Response ", response.json())
    return HttpResponse(response.json(), content_type='application/json')
```

When I make additional request to the Service Layer I get an error from the JSON Response.  Any insight or suggestions is much appreciated.  Thank you.

For example, if I make another request to any other end point I will get the error message below (GET https://sap_url.com:50000/b1s/v2/Orders).

/* Subsequent Calls require header info with authkey.  Body not needed */

def GetOpenOrders(request):

```
sap_url = "https://sap_url.com:50000/b1s/v2/Orders"
headers = {
    "authkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
}

response = requests.get(sap_url, headers=headers)
print("JSON Response ", response.json())
return HttpResponse(response.json(), content_type='application/json')
```

```
JSON Response  {'error': {'code': '301', 'message': 'Invalid session or session already timeout.'}}
```

Comment: I fixed the code formatting, but indentation is still wonky. Please take a moment to fix that.

Comment: I see a `return` here which means this is part of a function, but you didn't include the `def` line. Please [edit] your question to include a [mcve]. What causes the 301 response code? Please explain more about what actions cause this error.

Comment: Thanks for the comment.  made edits

Comment: Please show the relevant code that makes another request to SAP.

Answer (score 2):

I found a work around to this question and I hope it can help someone looking for a similar answer.

What I did was save the "SessionId" from the Login request and then add it to the "Cookie" inside the header.  So subsequent request will have "Cookie" inside the header.  I saw this as a workaround when I used Postman and saw the "Cookie" key and value in the header.

def GetOpenOrders(request):

```
sap_url = "https://sap_url.com:50000/b1s/v2/Orders"
headers = {
    "Cookie": "B1SESSION=SessionID; ROUTEID",
    "authkey": "XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX",
    "Accept": "*/*",
    "Content-Type": "text/plain",
}

response = requests.get(sap_url, headers=headers)
print("JSON Response ", response.json())
return HttpResponse(response.json(), content_type='application/json')
```

I manually tested by copy and pasting the SessionId to the "Cookie" value.  You would need to store the SessionId and pass it as a variable.

Comment: thank you so much, This solution is working for me