# 401 Not Authorized in SAP Business One Service Layer using UI-API Single Sign-On

Tags: sapb1

We are trying to use Service Layer via Single Sign On in UI-API add-on. We are able to get the service context - Session ID and run any call for reading data using GET. But we are trying to create sales quotations using POST and it returns with error 401 - Not Authorized with following message in response.

{ "error": { "code": 301, "message": { "lang": "en-us", "value": "Invalid session or session already timeout." } }}

Is POST not allowed via sessions obtained through single sign-on? If it is allowed than what are we doing wrong?

Comment: Does this answer your question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73777371/how-to-make-subsequent-request-to-sap-business-one-service-layer-from-django

Comment: Does this user you are using to log on have approptiate authorizations?